# How to kill Roscore programatically

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Pharo to launch roscore, and thus I cannot simply CTRL+C in the terminal, because that shuts down pharo as well. Pharo allows me to send commands to the console.
How do I end the roscore process, then, with a command? $ ps aux | grep ros gives me a list, but I need to automate the Roscore killing (for test purposes, I have to invoce roscore, run several tests, and then shut it down automatically).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199760/how-to-kill-roscore-programatically/) by [Demian S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/21164/demian-s./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-12-18**:
How do you actually start roscore? That is, I'd never heard of Pharo until your mention of it...if you can *start* a process, surely there's a way to *halt* it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have never heard of Pharo, but if you can send commands to a console, you can just use a command to stop the roscore process. For example in Ubuntu, just send the command "killall roscore" and the master should shutdown. Just a quick and dirty solution.

---

Originally posted by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) with karma: 305 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Demian S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/21164/demian-s./) on 2014-12-19**:
Thats it! It worked perfect, thanks a lot!